# How to export emails out of sendmail

Tags: sendmail

We have a centOS 5.6 with sendmail configured. We have quite a few email accounts which receive hundreds of emails a day. We have one particular account with thousdands of emails withint in, but we're unable to access it. It times out. I want to know if there is a way for me to access that account and export all of the emails out of this account so that we can start accessing it again. As of now, we're unable to and emails keep piling up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default installation delivers mail messages to /var/spool/mail/${USER}; that is a simple mbox-formatted text file. You can mv this file or simply rm it to clear the existing messages.

Comment: thanks, i looked at the size of this mailbox and its 2.6GB. It has 2.7 million emails. Its huge. Can you please give me exact command on how to move emails out of this? We need to keep all these emails. By the way, i have no knowledge of linux.

Comment: How do you want to keep the mails?
You could use Thunderbird to access the mails in the mbox file 
and export them if needed.

Comment: I tried to use Thunderbird, but it keeps timing out.

Comment: you could try the suggestions in this link, especially splitting the mbox file.
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Edit_large_mbox_files

Comment: we're using webmin and i found somewhere that i can download that mailbox to another local server. Will that work? While its downloading, will it prevent emails coming through?

Comment: I'm not sure how webmin accesses the mailbox for the download - if it does a simple FTP or SCP, then it should work. If it tries to use the POP3/IMAP protocols, you'll have the same problem with it as you do with Thunderbird. It won't prevent mails from being delivered, but it may not remove old mails after it's completed the download.

Comment: It appears that webmin is downloading the file and it will take well over 12 hours. Will wait and see what happens.